# Applescript help. Program won't end

Tags: applescript

So I'm new to applescript and I'm trying to create an app that will open microsoft word and then save the document every once in a while automatically and then stop running once I close Word. This is my code so far:

```
activate application "Microsoft Word"

     if application "Microsoft Word" is running then

          repeat

               delay 5

               tell application "Microsoft Word" to save front document

         end repeat

     end if
```

It works up until the point that I quit word.  Even though I have it set to end if word isn't running it still tries to save to word and then I get an error message. Another interesting thing to note is that it even says end tell in the script once I quit word.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're entering an infinite loop - you check if word is running, then start looping around and telling word to save. You don't ever check again to see if word is still running, so essentially you're just yelling "Hey word! Save!", never noticing that word packed up its things and went home.

Comment: Ya I know, just trying to mess around with coding a little.  I'm a freshman in engineering, so I'm trying to get used to how coding logic works.

Comment: ok, wasn't sure. Hey in this case you should also check out the code snippets that are included: ctrl-click into a script to get the menu.

Comment: Oh ok cool thanks. Also, switching the if and repeat loops didn't fix it.

Comment: Ah yes, also remove the first line because that activates Word. So the script would actually start with "repeat", followed by the if statement and so on.

Comment: 1. Are you sure you want to be saving every five seconds? That's an awful lot of disk activity per word. 2. Any particular reason you don't just use 'Word > Preferences > Save > Save AutoRecover info every _N_ minutes', which automatically saves backups for you? The default interval is every 10min, but you can change that. (If you're having a problem with recovered documents not reopening automatically, [this support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892956) explains how to reopen them yourself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save this as a stay-open application:

```
activate application "Microsoft Word"

    on idle
        say "idle"
        if application "Microsoft Word" is running then tell application "Microsoft Word" to save front document
        return 5 -- in seconds
    end idle
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you.  What do the idle and return commands mean?

Comment: Wait, actually know it if I click on it, it's not saving every 5 seconds anymore

Comment: From the AppleScript Language Guide: "If a stay-open script application includes an idle handler, AppleScript sends the script application periodic idle commands—by default, every 30 seconds—allowing it to perform background tasks when it is not performing other actions." The return statement specifies in seconds, how long until the next idle is called.

Comment: You are supposed to launch the application once and leave it.